# Can I run Internet Explorer with Watir Webdriver in Ubuntu?

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu, cucumber, watir-webdriver

http://watirwebdriver.com/internet-explorer/ hier I see, that Watir-Webdriver can start IE only with Windows. But is it even possible?

Answer (score 5):

The watir-webdriver library depends on the WebDriver project, and WebDriver's IE driver is only supported on Windows. IE is only supported on Windows. You might be tempted to try the Wine project, or some other Linux-to-Windows bridge library to attempt to run it on Linux. You might even be able to get it to work. But when you run into problems, and it's virtually guaranteed that you will, you're on your own in resolving them. Neither the IE driver nor IE itself has been tested to any degree with such a bridge library, so none of the developers thereof can guarantee with any certainty that the bridge environment isn't the root cause of the issue.

Given the ubiquity of virtual machine technology today, you're far, far better off using a virtual machine running a licensed copy of Windows. Microsoft even makes virtual machine images available for testing with IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Internet Explorer only on Windows, so Watir can drive it only on Windows.

Comment: I can install and run IE on Ubuntu with "wine". Thats why I ask, how can I start IE with watir-webdriver in my cucumber-test, which I start on Ubuntu. What I have to do? Is it generally possible?